# Images not displaying properly in Firefox

Tags: css

I am having an issue with Firefox rendering a few of the .png's that I have loaded into a Wordpress blog that I am preparing for a client. The images look fine in IE 8 & 9, and chrome, but it looks very off in Mozilla. I was informed by our other UX guy that Firefox complies with embedded color profiles that may warp the tint of your image. You can view the tint shift by going to :

http://blog.hendrickspower.com

If anybody has any idea of how to over ride the color profile, I'd definitely appreciate the heads up!

Thanks

Comment: The color profile comes from your image editing software. You'd set that up prior to exporting the PNG.

Comment: "off" and "Not displaying properly" are not very descriptive terms to use when describing image display issues. You've offered absolutely no information about how you are saving your pngs, what applications you are using or what exactly "off" means.

Comment: could you post screenshots of what the original images is supposed to look like and what the hosted image looks like?

Answer (score 1):

> If anybody has any idea of how to over ride the color profile, I'd definitely appreciate the heads up!

If you open the image in Photoshop, then use `Save For Web` and turn off `Convert to sRGB`, you'll end up with a PNG that matches the colour values and doesn't have an embedded ICC Color Profile (Photoshop doesn't save Color Profiles in PNG images, even though the PNG file format can include them).

Turning off `Convert to sRGB` is important — if you don't, the image will be destructively converted from the current profile to sRGB.